# AWS Iot Rule not getting triggered using MQTT browser client

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, amazon-sns

I have a SNS topic and subscriber set up like so :

[image]

The subscribers are correctly notified when the Topic is tested via "Publish to Topic" from AWS console

I have a IoT rule like so :

[image]

I have a policy attached to the rule like so :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sns:Publish",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-xxxxxx:MySNSTopic"
}
```

}

Yet when I try and test from the MQTT browser client, the notification is not fired

[image]
What am I missing?

Comment: I am using the MQTT test client and have the same issue. Any idea why that might be@Anshu Dutta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started working after a few minutes. Guess it needs some time to set up